# PHP return a string after a string, within a string

Tags: php, string

Lets say I have a string.  (looks like JSON but actually a string, and no, I cant convert it to JSON)

```
     "heresSome":"data", "moreData":"and some more data", "theDataIwant:["THE DATA I WANT", "AND MORE DATA", "DUNNO HOW LONG", "BUT IT ENDS IN A BRACKET"], "moredata";
```

I want to just retrieve...

```
   "THE DATA I WANT", "AND MORE DATA", "DUNNO HOW LONG", "BUT IT ENDS IN A BRACKET"
```

from that above string.

Anybody know of some PHP magic to do that?

Ive done this...and it works.  On a very small string such as the above.

```
$d = explode("theDataIwant:[", $string);
$d2 = explode("]", $d[1]);
var_dump($d2[0]); // returns THE DATA I WANT...etc
```

But the actual string I'm working with is huge, so this crashes when I try to run it. Maybe because got tons of weird white space and html tags as well?  I'm not sure.

I'm sure this is a job for regex, but I'm not a regex master :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using regex:

```
$str = '"heresSome":"data", "moreData":"and some more data", "theDataIwant:["THE DATA I WANT, AND MORE DATA, DUNNO HOW LONG, BUT IT ENDS IN A BRACKET"], "moredata"';
$re = '/"theDataIwant:\["([^"]+)"/m';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
echo($matches[0][1]);
```

Comment: What if the data is "theDataIwant":["THE DATA", "I WANT", "AND MORE"]  ?  so I want all the quotes and commas as well extracted

Comment: Try `$re = '/"theDataIwant:\[([^\]]+)\]/m';`, is this match your requirement?

Comment: PERFECT!! Thanks :)

Comment: Ok one last question.  What if I want "theDataIWant": "WANTED",  "but not thisdata":"not this".  So just one item in quotes after the string Im looking for

Comment: This is hard, I need some time for this.

Comment: Im thinking the : and the , can be used as 'brackets' of sorts?

Comment: What if there is `:` and `,` contain in the string?

Comment: I want to confirm one thing: is it true that the question string is `"theDataIwant:"...` or it's a typo in the question and the true string is `"theDataIwant":"...`?

Comment: And also the capitalize of `W` in `want`?

Comment: Try `$re = '/"theDataIWant": *(\[([^\]]+)\]|"[^"]+")/m';` and try [this](https://regex101.com/r/cvsMYo/1)